# Laravel controller gives not found error

Tags: laravel

I have installed **Laravel 4.2.11** using composer and have created an alias. Currently working on Wamp server.

I've created a controller named UserController.php under "app\controllers" location and edited the routes.php under "app". I have written the following code snippet in routes.php:

```
Route::resource('User','UserController');
```

However, when I want to access the url by typing http://localhost/laraveldemo/User, it shows a error message "Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ NotFoundHttpException". Please note that I have not created any view for this yet.

May be I'm missing something as I'm new about Laravel. Seeks your help.

Comment: Check if your UserController.php has index function.

Comment: Yes! Its include a "index()" function. So, I have written on this controller file as: return View::make('users'); and created a view named "users.php" under 'views' location; but when accessing the URL as http://localhost/laraveldemo/User/index, it shows error message. Kindly help me!

Comment: Do 1 thing, write echo "xyz"; exit; in your index function. and url will be: localhost/laraveldemo/User. See, if you get xyz.

Comment: Added echo "xyz"; as mentioned by you. But while accessing localhost/laraveldemo/User, it redirects me to http://localhost/User which leads to a not found page. Please note that I have wrote "Route::resource('User','UserController');" in routes.php.

Comment: run `php artisan route:list` in console (root dir of your project) and look which route used for your class UserController

Comment: @ dyachenko I typed the command at console screen, but it says that there is no such command available. Please advise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

> In your Routes.php

```
Route::get('/', function()
{
    return View::make('users');
});
```

**URL: localhost/laraveldemo**

.htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

See, if get users.php file.

Comment: Added as per your request, but facing the same error. FYI, I have enabled URL rewriting from apache through wamp. But note that I don't have any htaccess file within my Laravel application. Do you have any idea?

Comment: You must be having a hidden htaccess file in your public folder. If you can't find that then, you have to create htaccess file with above defined, default value.

Comment: Thanks for that. I checked and saw the default htaccess file within the public folder as you said. But I don't know why the application NOT run based on the controller that I have created.

Comment: Check your middleware code, it might be kicking inn. In the end you can try composer update/dumpautoload.

Comment: Today I've tested the application & Its working fine for me. Thanks a ton for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one possible reason (and solution)...

For Laravel's URL writer to work you must give the server permissions to rewrite the URL.

You can do this by accessing the Apache Modules list (open up the Wamp server settings and hover over Apache) and turn on the option 'rewrite_module'.

After turning this option on, restart the server. If this was indeed the problem then the URL should work.

Also, just a tip... (and maybe just my preference)... I would try to keep your URL as case-insensitive as possible.

```
Route::resource('user', 'UserController');
```

I hope this helps get ya going! Laravel is a fantastic framework!

**
EDIT: additional help for the .htaccess file

You also want a .htaccess file in your project root directory.

The contents of the file can include the following (I'm simply copy/pasting a working file for a currently active project)

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Thanks for your kind help. But seems the same problem while accessing the URL by http://localhost/laraveldemo/users or http://localhost/laraveldemo/user. I have already enabled URL rewrite option from wamp. But please note that I've not placed any htaccess file on the root of my application. Can you please help me in this regard? Should I create a .htaccess file for this?

Comment: Yes, you definitely want a .htaccess file in your project root. 

I will edit my answer with help for that.

Comment: I just see there is a default htaccess file within the public folder. However, the issue remains same.